# Saved GRUB Customizer and now can't access fedora

Tags: fedora, grub

I have dual booted my computer with Fedora 36 and Windows. I wanted to change the boot order on my computer and so I installed GRUB customizer on Fedora. GRUB Customizer did not show all of my OSs, as could be seen in GRUB. Rather only showed Windows and BIOS (UEFI Firmware Settings), I had accidentally saved the settings on GRUB Customizer, and now when I turn on my computer I am only given the option of accessing Windows or BIOS, and I cannot seem to find a way to edit GRUB from Windows nor access Fedora. How can I solve this to access Fedora?

When I go into the BIOS, my Fedora installation is still present in the boot order. Only on GRUB can I not find it.

Pastebin from boot repair: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/H7xbk7WGzX/

[image: Partitions as shown by GParted]

Comment: The pastebin says "You need to be logged in to view this paste."

Comment: Yeah unfortunately you need to make an account with them if you want to view the paste, I had to do that too

Comment: Grub customizer replaces the grub script files with its own proxy files. You need to totally reinstall grub to restore grub's files. You can manually boot from grub, use chroot to reinstall grub from chroot, or use Boot-Repair to reinstall grub or  Supergrub to boot. to manually boot you have to get to grub's terminal & manually type in boot stanza. https://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/

Comment: Boot off of a Fedora ISO written to a USB stick, and you should be able to boot a live OS. From there you can rescue your grub configuration. Grub customizer doesn’t understand the bootloader spec grub settings in Fedora and really should be removed from Fedora since it is so broken.

Comment: @oldfred I have tried using Boot-repair, however I do not receive the "Recommended pair" option, I have now just tried Supergrub from a USB however I do not receive the option to install grub onto my hard drive, only on the USB. This leads me to think I'd have to install Supergrub onto my actual hard drive for it to work. Which I'd prefer to avoid but if I have to then I will.

Comment: @jsbillings I tried this while following this https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/bootloading-with-grub2/#restoring-bootloader-using-live-disk, however I receive an error on the final step stating that "this utility cannot be used for EFI platforms because it does not support UEFI Secure Boot".

Comment: Did UEFI Secure Boot get turned on with an update? Windows may do an UEFI update, which can turn Secure boot on and maybe other UEFI default settings & turn on Windows fast start up setting. If UEFI, you want UEFI version of grub. If you booted live installed in UEFI mode, you should be able to use Boot-Repair's advanced mode. Some systems with LVM or other formats may need you to first manually mount /boot & / . How you boot install or repair flash drive, is then how it install. So you always want UEFI.

Comment: @oldfred UEFI Secure Boot is off. At this point I am considering deleting fedora and completely reinstalling it, as I have only had the OS for a few days and can reinstall everything I need to.

Comment: I have reinstalled Fedora and this has fixed the issue. I am unsure if there are other solutions however this is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found a solution that would not require reinstalling, though I am not entirely sure as I do not have this problem anymore. When using commands such as `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`. It would find Windows Boot Manager and UEFI Firmware settings. Leading me to believe that this is not an issue with GRUB Customizer.

I was trying to install a grub theme and at first it was not working, until I found this https://github.com/VandalByte/grub-tweaks#-fix-for-grub-theme-not-showing-up--fedora-ubuntu-. After changing `/etc/default/grub`. Running `grub2-mkconfig` again would show all linux distributions that I normally saw on GRUB. Leading me to believe that if I had not reinstalled fedora, this would be my solution.